# First order partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Suppose that $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ has $C^1$ partial derivatives in some ball $B_r(x_0,y_0)$ $r>0$. Prove that if $\Delta_f(x_0,y_0)\neq 0$, then

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f_1^{-1}}{\partial x}(f(x_0,y_0))= \displaystyle\frac{\partial f_2/\partial y(x_0,y_0)}{\Delta_f(x_0,y_0)}$

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f_1^{-1}}{\partial y}(f(x_0,y_0))= \displaystyle\frac{\partial f_1/\partial y(x_0,y_0)}{\Delta_f(x_0,y_0)}$

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f_2^{-1}}{\partial x}(f(x_0,y_0))= \displaystyle\frac{\partial f_2/\partial x(x_0,y_0)}{\Delta_f(x_0,y_0)}$

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f_2^{-1}}{\partial xy}(f(x_0,y_0))= \displaystyle\frac{\partial f_1/\partial x(x_0,y_0)}{\Delta_f(x_0,y_0)}$

Please can someone show me only one equation? And then I Will beraber to solve second equation by myself. Thank you

Comment: What does $\Delta_f(x_0,y_0)$ means?

Comment: $:=detD(f(x_0,y_0))$ @trash

Comment: @trash thank you for edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove all of them at once. Recall the inverse function theorem: Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuously differentiable in an open set containing $a$ and $\det f'(a) \neq 0 $. Then there is an open set $V$ containing $a$ and an open set $W$ containing $f(a)$ such that $f : V \to W$ has a continuous inverse $f^{-1} : W \to V$ which is differentiable and for all $y \in W$ satisfies:

$$(f^{-1})'(y)=\left[f'(f^{-1}(y))\right]^{-1}$$

Notice that your $f$ is continuously differentiable in $B_r(x_0,y_0)$ (which is an open set) and recall that if $f'(x_0,y_0)$ is the jacobian matrix, then by your hypothesis we have that $\det f'(x_0, y_0) \neq 0$. So your function fits the hypothesis of the theorem. Then there must be an open set $V$ containing $(x_0,y_0)$ and an open set $W$ containing $f(x_0,y_0)$ such that $f : V \to W$ has continuous inverse $f^{-1} :  W \to V$ which is differentiable for all $(a,b) \in W$. And such that the jacobian matrix at each point $(a,b) \in W$ is given by the rule:

$$(f^{-1})'(a,b)=\left[f'(f^{-1}(a,b))\right]^{-1}$$

Take now $(a,b)=f(x_0,y_0)$. Then we have:

$$(f^{-1})'(f(x_0,y_0))=\left[f'(f^{-1}(f(x_0,y_0)))\right]^{-1}$$

But $f^{-1}(f(x_0,y_0)) = (x_0,y_0)$ so that this is the same as:

$$(f^{-1})'(f(x_0,y_0))=\left[f'(x_0,y_0)\right]^{-1}$$

Now can you procede from here?

Comment: Sorry, but no, I cannot:( Will I find the jacobian matrix of $f'(x_0,y_0)$ and then will I find the inverse of the matrix ?

Comment: By the way, you explanation part is so good:) thanks:)

Comment: Yes, this gives the jacobian matrix of $f^{-1}$ at the point $f(x_0,y_0)$ as the inverse of the jacobian matrix of the function $f$ at the point $(x_0,y_0)$. But you know the format of the jacobian matrix: it's the matrix of partials, and sice the jacobian will be $2\times 2$, it's inverse is easy to find. This will relate the partials of the components of the inverse and the partials of the components of the function you started with. Try writing all of this, if you still cannot do, try to explain where you are stuck.

Comment: That's, $\begin{pmatrix} \partial f_1/\partial x & \partial f_1 / \partial y \\ \partial f_2 /\partial x & \partial f_2 /\partial y \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: My friend wrote the matrix.(sorry I dont write this by myself, I dont know enough MathJax)  Now, I Will take its inverse. But I dont know how to take it:( then, I Will reach the result given at the question. Is it?

Comment: @Rsm1, it's the usual inverse of a matrix of $2$ lines and two columns. If you search on the internet, or even here on Math.SE, you'll see how to invert it. Then, you will have a matrix on the left hand side with the derivatives you want, and a matrix on the right hand side. You match the entries and you'll get what you want.